# how to make a Jbutton do multiple things

Tags: java, awt, swingx

I'm trying to creating an Interface that work like a Terminale in Linux
so I have a TextArea where I print and a TextField where I write and a Button that When I press should send data from TextField to TextArea

the problem now is each time I should do somthing different with what I got from My JTextField. and one listener doesn't help me like for exemple this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object o = e.getSource();

    if (o == ButtonCharger){
         // have multiple tests here and the "o" is diffrent each time 

    }
}
```

I did many test but never works like I want I cauldn't make one JButton do multiple taches

I apologize about My English

Comment: Consider simplifying things: create and post a small runnable program that tries to do what you're describing, one without extra functions that aren't relevant to your problem, a [mcve]

Comment: you got a point sorry I didnt Thought about this

Answer (score 0):

What if you base your actions on the value you get from your JTextField,

```
private JTextField tField = new JTextField();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object o = e.getSource();

    if(jField.getText().equals("YOUR STRING 1")) {

        //do something
    }
    else if(jField.getText().equals("YOUR STRING 2")) {

        //do somehting else
    }
    else {

        //don't do anything
    }
}
```

Comment: I m creating a system expert this can't work for me cause i test with data from a file so you can imagine like the user is communicating with the programme like for exemple : [ prog : insert you base , user: insert somthing, prog: existe in the base you wanna modifie , user: yes ,  ... ]  and the prog still ask intil until the user get "done" so he move for an other think